# Where does the file go after bluetooth tranfer?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Bluez bluetooth Manager, after I send the files from my Android device to the Laptop which contains Linux Mate with the standard File System. I cannot seem to find the files which a received in this manner. The Bluez documentation does not specify where do these files go.

Comment: Most likely it's in your home folder somewhere. You can find the file location with `find /home/username -type f -name "filename" -print` command in terminal

Comment: Agreed, it will go to your home folder unless you tell it different

Answer (score 0):

By default in Ubuntu, received bluetooth files are found in `~/Downloads`

Answer (score 0):

I found images sent from my phone via Bluetooth in the

```
~/Public
```

folder.